# How can I do advanced routing with Jetty?

Tags: java, routes, jetty

I recently started working with jetty embedded, and I would like to know if you can do some more advanced routing with it.

I figured out how to handle a request like this: `url/{servlet}/{param}`, but I'm stuck on how to do something like `url/{servlet}/{param}/{servlet}/{param}`

For example, assume I have a user servlet and a shopping cart servlet.

I would like to be able to call the shopping cart for the user with the id `1234` with `url/user/1234/cart/addsomething`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use the public standards (like `javax.servlet`, or something non-standard and unique offered by Jetty?)  Also, are you using standard webapps/wars on standalone Jetty, or are you using embedded-jetty?

Comment: I'm happy with everything (standart or jetty), and I'm using jetty embedded. @JoakimErdfelt